# Refresh javascript if else statment not working

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

hi everyone I am new to Javascript and would like to know how would I refresh an if else statement in javascript every 5 seconds, i have looked and cannot get anything to work thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                if(total == randnum) {
                    document.write('Correct');
                } else {
                    document.write('Incorrect');
                }

 </script>
```

Comment: Take a look at `setInterval()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to write out the document or can you display the text in some element like a `div`?

If so then you can try something similar to what 'chopper' suggested:

Assuming you have a `div` in your page with the id "myDiv"

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Then use this to write out your text:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
setInterval(function () {
    if(total == randnum) {
        myDiv.innerHTML = "Correct";
    } else {
        myDiv.innerHTML = "Incorrect";
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: this one did the trick this is me being a newbie and thought i had to use document.write :) thank you and everyone else

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code you want to repeat inside a function an use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) (click for documentation with examples) for repeating it.

```js
myFunction() {
    //...
    // Your code
    //...
} 

setInterval(myFunction, 5000);
```

And if you want it to start immediately and then repeat:

```
myFunction();
setInterval(myFunction, 5000);
```

Answer (score -1):

[`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) will execute a given function periodically, for example like this:

```
setInterval( function() {
    if(total == randnum) {
        $('#result').append('Correct<br/>');
    } else {
        $('#result').append('Incorrect<br/>');
    }
}, 5000);
```

Where

Of course you will have to define `total` and `randnum`.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pagd8/).

Comment: Not going to work...Yes setInterval is right, but the document write is going to break it.

Comment: i have already defined the variables sorry for that misunderstanding :)  all setinterval is doing is opening a new page and keep repeating the word correct over and over again.

Comment: Then the issue is not with setInterval, the issue you're having is with your variables `total` and `randnum`